# Не получается сделать SELECT с помощью doctrine2 orm. Использую бд: postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, orm, doctrine2

Вот код:

```
$dql = 'SELECT name_serial FROM serial';
$query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql);
$query->setMaxResults(30);
$result = $query->getResult();
echo json_encode($result);
```

Но в результате получаю ошибку:

```
Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: SELECT name_serial FROM serial in /home/{username}/Serials/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:41
```

Обернул в try-catch и в результате увидел такую ошибку: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 24 near 'serial': Error: Class 'serial' is not defined.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно было бы исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы пишите SQL запрос, а Doctrine понимает только DQL.

```
SELECT u FROM MyProject\Model\User u WHERE u.age > 20
```

Создайте и опишите модели для доступа к БД, обратитесь к ним в вашем DQL с помощью их пространств имен.

Подход основанный на **прямом доступе** к базе данных также поддерживается компонентом **DBAL Doctrine**, но крайне нежелателен при работе с базой данных, если вы решили использовать ORM.

**Однако** этот подход наиболее эффективен при работе с огромным количеством записей. Стоит использовать его в крошечных скриптах для обработки больших объемов данных.

[Подробнее о DQL на официальном сайте](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)

[Подробнее о DBAL на официальном сайте](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/)